# Should we merge "errors" into "exceptions" tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, retag-request

Should we merge [errors](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/errors) into [exceptions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exceptions)?

Comment: This should be tagged with "tags". Or when we have reached a resolution with "retag-request". :)

Comment: Will do next time. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[exceptions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exceptions) is better than [errors](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/errors), but neither is a good tag. The problem is that any software can have them and the tags will get stuck on everything from "human errors to errors in any kind of software in the space".

I.e. both [errors](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/errors) and [exceptions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exceptions) only work well if there is another tag that further specifies them. Then it is better to make the tag more specific:

- [error](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/error) + [contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contracts) should go to [contract-debugging](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contract-debugging)
- [go-ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go-ethereum) + [exception](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exception) should go to [go-ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go-ethereum) or if there are enough questions to [go-ethereum-errors](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/go-ethereum-errors)
- …

Comment: The most common exception/error is "out-of-gas", and all current questions tagged with [tag:exceptions] can actually be tagged with "out-of-gas".  Should we replace/rename [tag:exceptions] with "out-of-gas"?  Then should we also delete [tag:errors] ?

Comment: Out-of-gas sounds much more specific, so I'd think that would be a good idea (I don't know a whole lot about Ethereum though).

Comment: ok, I asked here: http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/89/42  Let me know if a new question shouldn't have been asked.  Thanks

Comment: @eth: I would have probably posted it as another answer here instead since it aims to resolve the issue asked here. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip and will get better at it and know for next time :)