# Should we retag "exceptions" to "out-of-gas"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[Should we merge "errors" into "exceptions" tags?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87/should-we-merge-errors-into-exceptions-tags) suggested that [exceptions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exceptions) is too general.

Since "out-of-gas" is the most common exception/error in Ethereum, should we retag/rename [exceptions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exceptions) to [out-of-gas](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/out-of-gas) ?  It fits all questions currently tagged with [exceptions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exceptions).

Comment: Bad JUMPDEST exceptions are also quite [common](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/694/131)

Comment: But aren't most of those "Bad JUMPDEST" due to out-of-gas instead of handwritten bytecode that specified an invalid jumpdest ?

Comment: Yes, but it would be confusing for someone experiencing a JUPDEST error to tag their post with a GAS exception. Just using the "exception" tag seems more general and intuitive to me.

Comment: Agreed with Tjaden, maybe we just want to add an [tag:out-of-gas] tag instead of using it as a replacement.

Comment: Agree with having tags for specific exceptions. Technically these are halting-exceptions and I think it's appropriate to have multiple tags because there can also be a solidity-exception (which is different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, this works very well for all 4 questions being tagged with [exceptions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exceptions)

Answer (score 2):

Please use both tags.   The error message in the geth logfile is "Out of Gas".  New devs don't always know they are related.  As a matter of fact, I recall finding out the hard way that throw in solidity uses up all available gas.

Comment: Agree if both can fit.  I tried adding back exceptions tag to your question, but not sure which tag should be booted out to make room for it...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest using out-of-gas and evm-exception. Solidity has exceptions too so "exception" maybe too generic. "exception" isn't so bad if its alongside one of the other tags.